# node-red timeout with nginx reverse proxy and auth basic

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, node-red

I have nginx configured as a reverse proxy to a node-red server. Everything works normally until I add the auth_basic to the config file.

I get prompted for login which accepts details without issue and loads up the node-red admin page.

However within 30secs I get "lost connection to server" error :/

The nginx error log shows the following error which is repeated over and over.

`[17/Nov/2017:20:35:00 +1100] "GET /comms HTTP/1.1" 401 188 "-" ...`

My nginx site file -

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name my.domain.com;

    location / {
        auth_basic "Security";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        proxy_pass http://10.0.1.107:1880/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That error implies that WebSockets are not being proxied properly

Comment: @hardillb yeh thats what I gathered from looking for a solution. So what I did was move the NR admin location and dashboard location and this solved the problem. Why? don't know, I am just happy its working.